# Confused about the different terminology with .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, terminology

What is the difference between .net and asp.net? Which role does PHP more closely fill?

If someone was developing a website using asp.net and C#, how would you communicate that idea to a colleague, i.e. what's the language you would use?

Answer (score 9):

From the [Wiki's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework),

> The [`.NET Framework`](http://www.microsoft.com/net/) (pronounced dot
>   net) is a software framework that runs
>   primarily on Microsoft Windows. It
>   includes a large library and supports
>   several programming languages which
>   allows language interoperability (each
>   language can use code written in other
>   languages). The .NET library is
>   available to all the programming
>   languages that .NET supports. Programs
>   written for the .NET Framework execute
>   in a software environment (as
>   contrasted to hardware environment),
>   known as the Common Language Runtime
>   (CLR), an application virtual machine
>   that provides important services such
>   as security, memory management, and
>   exception handling. The class library
>   and the CLR together constitute the
>   .NET Framework.

`.NET` is a way for many different programming languages to use the same classes, namespaces and other resources.

From the [Wiki's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asp.net),

> [`ASP.NET`](http://www.asp.net/) is a web application
>   framework developed and marketed by
>   Microsoft to allow programmers to
>   build dynamic web sites, web
>   applications and web services. ASP.NET
>   is built on the Common Language
>   Runtime (CLR), allowing programmers to
>   write ASP.NET code using any supported
>   .NET language.

Comment: Why -1 ? .. Please care to comment ..

Comment: While I wasn't the downvoter, your initial post was quite different where you referenced classic ASP where the poster was speaking to ASP.NET. Only thing I can think of.

Comment: That was my fault -- I thought you were done writing at ".NET is a framework........." which (while true) is uh, not exactly a useful answer to the question. I've changed my down vote to an up vote.

Comment: @Khepri : I see ... Anyway, I updated the answer.

Comment: @Jeremy : Ya ... I was writing the answer the full answer, so took time to complete it. Anyway, thanks for your change of vote ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`.net` is an entire framework and suite of interoperating languages, capable of doing everything from web applications to console apps, to rich client applications.  `ASP.net` is more particularly a web programming framework, but many of the .net languages and most of the .net library is accessible to asp.net applications.

PHP, I suppose, is more like ASP.net.

If you're looking for suggestions, `Asp.net all the way!`  (But it's all in what your team is comfortable with).

Comment: Asp.net is cool until you discover MVC :)

Comment: @Nick Just for clarity, ASP.NET MVC is built on ASP.NET, as it's name implies...

Comment: @Eric, I'm sure you'll agree that Asp.net usually refers to webforms, not its MVC counterpart.

Comment: @Nick No, I wouldn't say that at all. ASP.NET refers to way more than the view engine. Most of ASP.NET is used by both MVC and Web Forms. I think it's important not to conflate the terms, because you'll just end up confusing people more when they're trying to get their terminology straight.

Answer (score 0):

C# **IS** the language (or VB.Net), ASP.Net is the set of tools that references the .Net framework, allowing developers to create dynamic websites that can run on web servers that support ASP.Net (Usually IIS). Visual Studio is the development environment most commonly used by developers to create ASP.Net websites.